# Assets pipeline rails Heroku

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

Recently I upgraded my project to Rails 5 and I'm going crazy with the assets pipeline when trying to upload everything to Heroku.

The issue is the following: I have a collection of Ejercicios and, when u click on one of them, the app should show its information, including an image. The routes to the images are stored in my db like this `img1: "ejercicios/abdominales/1_4_I1.bmp"`. That file, for example, would be on `app/assets/images/ejercicios/abdominales/1_4_I1.bmp`.

The related view `show.html.haml` prints the images like this: `= image_tag(@ejercicio.img1) if @ejercicio.img1?`.

It worked perfectly on local but not in production in Heroku, so read about [the assets pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) in order to make it work. So I changed my `show.html.haml` like this: `= image_tag asset_path(@ejercicio.img1) if @ejercicio.img1?` and I added the lines the tutorial mentions in Gemfile and application.rb. The executed `bundle install` and `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, added the new 'public' folder to my git, committed and pushed my git, and finally pushed everything to heroku.

But it doesn't work, the 'alt' of the image is shown. Using the inspector I can see that the images in the html follow the normal url to the image and not the one with the fingerprint, so the helper `asset_path` seems not to be working properly.

Here's my `production.rb` in `config/environments`

```
KeepMeFit::Application.configure do

  config.eager_load = true
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = falsenginx

  config.force_ssl = true

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify


  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://keepmefit.herokuapp.com/"}
end
```

My 'application.rb' in 'config':

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

require 'will_paginate/array'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module KeepMeFit
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :es

    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]

    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.serve_static_assets = true

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    config.assets.version = '1.0'

  end
end
```

And my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.3'

gem 'rails', '5.1.4'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'activemodel'
  gem 'json'

    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'rb-notifu'
    # gem 'railroady'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
    gem 'launchy'
end

group :development do
    gem 'annotate'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
end


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
    gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw, :mingw]

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'

require 'rbconfig'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/i

gem 'modernizr-rails'

#gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'tzinfo-data'

gem 'faker', '1.1.2'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'friendly_id'

gem 'gon'

gem 'cloudinary'
```

Comment: Just to confirm: Did you pushed to `master` branch? As, heroku will use `master` branch by default.

Comment: Yes, this is driving me crazy

Comment: As per Heroku guide line, you are not suppose to push pre-compiled assets. Check this debugging steps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#debugging

Comment: Do the images change? Or are they supposed to not change on a regular base - like js or css files change quite often while developing new features? Because you store references to that images into the DB, I guess they do not. And if they do not change why use the asset pipeline for that kind of images. Just put them into the public folder.

Comment: Thank you @spickermann, that solved my problem. I am new with rails and I thought every image had to be uploaded via assets pipeline. Write an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asset pipeline has basically two use-cases:

First, it precompiles and combines various stylesheets or JavaScript file into single bundles. Being able to precompile — for example — SCSS to CSS simplifies development. And one big combined files can be downloaded faster than many small files.

Second, it adds hashes to the filenames. This allows caching these files for a long time, which improves performance too. Even if there is only a small change in one of the files, then the hash and therefore the filename will change. The changed filename will not be in the cache and therefore the browser reloads the file immediately.

But in your case, your images are static anyway. There is no point precompiling images and adding hashes to files that are not supposed to change.

Therefore, I would just put that images directly into the public folder and would bypass the asset pipeline for these kinds of static images.